# Laravel 5.1 returns wrong config value

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, config

I have a custom Laravel config file called config/alfresco.php. The file is a special file to keep Alfresco config connection. Here is what it is look like:

```
   <?php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| CMIS BROWSER URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The address of Alfresco server
|
*/
// http://<another IP>:9080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser
'CMIS_BROWSER_URL' => 'http://192.168.1.5:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| CMIS BROWSER USER
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Alfresco username credential
|
*/

'CMIS_BROWSER_USER' => 'admin',
```

I tried to get the config's value by calling the following:

```
Config::get('alfresco.CMIS_BROWSER_URL');
```

However, it seems always to return wrong value. In my case, it is:

```
http://<another IP>:9080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser
```

Note that the value that is called is the one that is commented. I tried to get rid of it, but it still comes with the same result. I am sure that the  value is only appear on this config.

My another attempt is to do:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

And it came with no luck.
Thanks in advance :)

---

Solution:

Thanks to @James for pointing out the solution, it is:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

I am sure it was a cache on Laravel configuration. Hope this help for others :)

Comment: In addition to what @Gagan has suggested, try running `php artisan config:clear` - let me know how you get on.

Comment: Yes, that is it, @James. php artisan config:clear works for me very well. Thank you very much

Comment: @James can you please make your comment an answer , in case Restu Arif Priyono wants to mark it as the correct answer .. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have changed some values in your config files, you should make sure you have cleared any cached versions of these - otherwise they won't reflect the latest changes.

To do this, just run `php artisan config:clear`.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried this ?

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```

Running the above command will recompile all the files.

Thanks

GJ

Note: Please mark this answer as resolved, if you think this resolved your issue . This might help someone coming in next.

Comment: I think what you meant is composer dump-autoload? I tried that, and still no luck. But, what @James suggested is the one that actually work! It is php artisan config:clear. Thanks, guys. You saved my day

Comment: Nope there is a php artisan dump-autoload command as well :) .. Good for you that it worked. :)

Comment: @Gagan I think what you mean is `php artisan clear-compiled`. php artisan dump-autoload is not a valid command